# What is the correct BING Search API GET URL?

Tags: rest, get, bing, bing-api

I am trying to figure out how I can do a simple REST call in my app with BING Search API.

With Google the URL I use is something like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=HERE_IS_THE_KEY&cx=HERE-IS_APP_ID&searchType=image&lr=lang_no&q=pepsimax

I can't seem to find BING's version of this. I can't even find where I add a new APP in the control panel.

Anyone know the BING url to query search and where in the control panel to add a new app?

Comment: Version 5 of Bing Search API, now part of Microsoft Cognitive Services, is out - https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation

Answer (score 0):

The query URLs have changed from http://api.bing.net in the Bing Search API 2.0 to the following in Windows Azure Marketplace. The one that you use depends on which product offering you've subscribed to.
Product offering    Query URL
Bing Search API     https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/

Bing Search API - Web Results Only  https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/

For Web Result:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/bing/search/web?format=json&query=%27Your_search_Keyword%27

[Here](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) is the documentation available.